# Set CSS style attributes on expanded kendo drop down

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

My list is different, but a good starting reference is at https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index

I need to set the maximum height of a Kendo DropDownList. The list has no header, N elements and a footer that contains a button to add more elements. After a certain threshold, say 8 items, I want it to turn on the vertical scroll bar and fix the height at this maximum. I'm not picky about the exact height, but it's probably about 400px.

I can and have set the "height" option, but the after a certain threshold, the footer goes below  (and outside) the list of items. Kendo height seems to not take into account the footer height, but can't be certain.

Kendo decided to put the content in this totally separate area from the original selector. Unfortunately, I need to style this separate HTML. That is, I want to style the div.k-animation-container and below. And, most importantly, I want to style different dropdowns differently, so I can't use a generic style.

How do I style Kendo elements that descend from .k-animation-container?

For the moment, I'm cheating by adding an id to the footer, finding that and looking for the closest .k-animation-container. But I want to style the .k-animation-container directly.

I'm not sure it's relevant, but I built this Kendo dropdown component using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the animation container directly (unless there can only be one on the page). You can avoid inserting the ID by using the .popup property of the dropdown control. For example, handle the [open](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/open) event:

```
open: function(e) {                      
   var $pop = e.sender.popup.element;                      
   $pop.closest('.k-animation-container').css('height', 'auto');
   $pop.css('height', 'auto');
   $pop.find('.k-list').css('height', 'auto').css('max-height', '400px');                      
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/epUQofin)**

Change the 'NumberOfItems' variable to see the drop down height grow until a max of 400px.